# Kendo UI grid accessibility for button e.g. Excel Export

Tags: html, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, accessibility

How can I set the icon of the grid button to **aria-hidden="true"**?

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: ["excel"],
    excel: {
        allPages: true
    },
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10
    },
    pageable: true
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="grid"></div>
```

Current html:

```
<div class="k-header k-grid-toolbar"><a role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-i-file-excel"></span>Export to excel</a></div>
```

Desired result:

```
<div class="k-header k-grid-toolbar"><a role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel" href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="k-icon k-i-file-excel"></span>Export to excel</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The icon has class `k-i-file-excel`.  Use that class to select the element and set the attribute:

```
$("#grid .k-i-file-excel").attr("aria-hidden","true");
```

Comment: This is an example of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): sure, it will add the attribute, but it will add nothing to the accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything.

Test your application with a keyboard and screen reader. Since you're not modifying tab indices, either the outer `<a>` tag will get the focus (and should be correctly announced as "Export to excel"), or nothing will. Your user will know what the button is for.